# In VSTO how can I delete rows from a Table in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a table in an Excel worksheet where I need to programatically remove entire rows using VSTO. After a lot of searching here and everywhere else, I was unable to find the answer. Due to some unrelated code, I also cannot delete the first row of the table, but need to remove all other rows.

Here are the specific requirements:

- One of the functions of this addin is to populate the table. This is done through a loop starting with the "root" named range in the left column of the first row of the table.
- Whenever populating the table, I first need to delete all data from the table and then add the new data. I need to use the "root" to add the data, so I can't have it deleted.
- I am using the Table for the automated formatting instead of formatting the table manually after adding each cell.
- I never know how many rows will be added, but it will always be at least one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head on this for a few hours, I slept on it and came at it refreshed this morning. After much trial and error, here is the code I came up with.

```
var deplTable = ThisSheet.Evaluate("DeploymentTable");

if (deplTable.ListObject.ListRows.Count > 1)
    {
        do deplTable.ListObject.ListRows[2].Delete();
            while (deplTable.ListObject.ListRows.Count > 1);
    }
```

***NOTE***: ThisSheet is set to the correct sheet earlier. The application works on multiple sheets, so it needs to be flexible.

I tried this a few ways before finally getting it to work. Looping through the rows gave unexpected results; possibly due to timing issues between Excel and VSTO.

Hope this helps other people!